# How to backup and restore scm manager server?

Tags: version-control, centos

I am having scm manager server i need to same setup and same code backup server.
so i am plaining to configured centos 6.3 server i was download it scm manager server. But how to backup old scm manager server full repository and full data, username and all.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take only repository backup, You can just write scripts to take backup of all repositories with simple steps.

1. Change the directory where you want to take backup of repos
2. git clone --mirror RepoURL

Restore -

change the directory where you have repo backup, if you are going to restore this repo in another server you need to change the origin url in config file

eg: Backup folder name is Backupmygitrepo.git, within this folder "config" will be available.

url = URLofNewOrigin

Execute below command for restore your repo-

git clone Backupmygitrepo.git restorereponame

This will restore repository with history.